# D3 hierarchy collapse to first level by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have the below code for an indented tree.  I am wanting to collapse the tree by default and have only the 1st level children show or the root node, doesn't matter.  I have tried a couple approaches that I thought would work without success, and the current portion below I thought would do the trick:

```
function toggleAll(d) {
                   if (d.children) {
                   d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(d);
                   }
               }

                 root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(root);
                  });
```

Below is the html with corresponding flare.json file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 960,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 400,
    root;

var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.x; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width) // + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  if (error) throw error;
  root = d3.hierarchy(flare);
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;
  update(root);

function toggleAll(d) {
                   if (d.children) {
                   d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(d);
                   }
               }

                 root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(root);
                  });


function update(source) {

  // Compute the flattened node list.
  var nodes = root.descendants();



  var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  d3.select("svg").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("height", height);

  d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  root.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes.
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", .5);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3.5)
      .attr("dx", 5.5)
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

   // Transition nodes to their new position.
  nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);

  node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();

  // Update the links.
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.links(), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  root.each(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}



// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}




function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

flare.json

```
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2200, 
      "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 800,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 600,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 300,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 250,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 250,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 525,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 375,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 265,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 136,  "color" : "red"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 100,  "color" : "red"}
     ]


      },
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1400, 
       "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 525,  "color" : "aqua"},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 375,  "color" : "aqua"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 265,  "color" : "aqua"},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 136,  "color" : "aqua"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 100,  "color" : "aqua"}
     ]},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1200,  "color" : "green"},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 825,  "color" : "blue"},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 400,  "color" : "purple"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your code by adding toggle(Click) after data is ready. See following demo, not sure whether you want this or something else?

```js
var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 20
    },
    width = 960,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var i = 0,
    duration = 400,
    root;

var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width) // + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var flare = getFlare();
//d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
//    if (error) throw error;
    root = d3.hierarchy(flare);
    root.x0 = 0;
    root.y0 = 0;
    update(root);

    function toggleAll(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
            //toggle(d);
            click(d)
        }
    }

    root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    //toggle(root);
//});


function update(source) {

    // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = root.descendants();



    var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    d3.select("svg").transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style("height", height + "px");

    // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
    var index = -1;
    root.eachBefore(function(n) {
        n.x = ++index * barHeight;
        n.y = n.depth * 20;
    });

    // Update the nodes.
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .style("opacity", .5);

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
        .attr("height", barHeight)
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", 3.5)
        .attr("dx", 5.5)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.name;
        });

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        })
        .style("opacity", 1);

    node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .select("rect")
        .style("fill", color);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    // Update the links.
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(root.links(), function(d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x0,
                y: source.y0
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x,
                y: source.y
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    root.each(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}



// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}




function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}
function getFlare(){
  return {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "DataEvent",
       "size": 2200,
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "DataEvent",
         "size": 800,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "SelectionEvent",
         "size": 600,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 300,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "VisualizationEvent",
         "size": 250,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 250,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "DataEvent",
         "size": 525,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "SelectionEvent",
         "size": 375,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 265,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "VisualizationEvent",
         "size": 136,
         "color": "red"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 100,
         "color": "red"
        }
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "SelectionEvent",
       "size": 1400,
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "DataEvent",
         "size": 525,
         "color": "aqua"
        },
        {
         "name": "SelectionEvent",
         "size": 375,
         "color": "aqua"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 265,
         "color": "aqua"
        },
        {
         "name": "VisualizationEvent",
         "size": 136,
         "color": "aqua"
        },
        {
         "name": "TooltipEvent",
         "size": 100,
         "color": "aqua"
        }
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "TooltipEvent",
       "size": 1200,
       "color": "green"
      },
      {
       "name": "VisualizationEvent",
       "size": 825,
       "color": "blue"
      },
      {
       "name": "TooltipEvent",
       "size": 400,
       "color": "purple"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
}
```

```css
.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to help.

Looking at

```
function toggleAll(d) {
                   if (d.children) {
                   d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(d);
                   }
               }

                 root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                  toggle(root);
                  });
```

I think that

```
                  });
```

shouldn't be there.

Nice recursive function!
Just re-indenting it:

```
function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
  }
}
```

A little adjustment for calling it:

```
toggleAll(root);
```

^ will toggle all off.  note: if anything is already toggled off (with click), it will be toggled on,
and then

```
toggle(root);
```

^ will toggle root (only) back on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @iAmOren but I don't think I quite understand:

    `function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
      }
    }

    toggleAll(root);
    toggle(root);`

Doesn't seem to get me there....where am I wrong?